# Bucket Sort - Segmentation error

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, asymptotic-complexity, bucket-sort

So I used quicksort in my program but now want to reduce my complexity to O(n). I need to use bucket sort for this to work.

**That my program does**

My program reads in a file of integers, and the number of integers in the file, and outputs the lowest number in the file which exceeds at least 90% of the numbers in the file.

I did managed to get this to work, using quicksort.
However, I am not getting the right output with bucket sort and I have no idea why, because my code seems to be correct.

I get a segmentation fault when running it

**My code for Bucket sorting & outputting the result**

```
void Bucket_Sort(int array[], int n)
{   
 int i, j;   
 int count[n];  
 for(i=0; i < n; i++)
 {   
  count[i] = 0;   
 }     
 for(i=0; i < n; i++)
 {    
  (count[array[i]])++; 
 }     
 for(i=0,j=0; i < n; i++)
 {   
  for(; count[i]>0;(count[i])--) 
  {       
   array[j++] = i; 
  }  
 }   
}    Bucket_Sort(array, numberOfNumbers);   

     //Output the lowest number in the file which exceeds at least 90% of the numbers in the file.
     for (count = floor(0.9 * numberOfNumbers); count < numberOfNumbers; count ++)
     {
      if (array[count] != array[count + 1])
     {
      output = array[count];
      break;    
     }  
     }  
      printf("The outputs is : "); 
      printf("%d \n", output);
```

My program outputs compiles and but I get a Segmentation Fault when running it.

Any ideas regarding what I am doing wrong in my BucketSort?

Thank you,

Danielle

Comment: Consider formatting your code a little better, it's quite hard to read in its current state.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll change it now. I also found a bug in my code so i will update it now.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines together are a problem, if `n` is <20 and `array` contains numbers up to 703K

```
int count[n];  
(count[array[i]])++;
```

you are writing waaaay out of bounds.

Try this:

```
void Bucket_Sort(int array[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    int *count = NULL;

    // find largest
    int mymax = array[0]+1;
    for (i=1; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if (mymax < (array[i]+1))
            mymax = array[i]+1;
    }

    // allocate and zero-fill a proper-sized array
    count = calloc(mymax, sizeof(*count));

    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
        (count[array[i]])++;

    for(i=0,j=0; i < mymax; i++)
    {
        for(; count[i]>0;(count[i])--)
            array[j++] = i;
    }
    free(count);
}
```

Comment: How do I need to change them in order to avoid getting the Segmentation fault I am getting at the moment? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Danielle review the bucket sort algorithm. It hinges on your `count[]` array being *indexible* using *values* of your incoming array as indices, and must be sized to meet that requirement. If needed, and with AShelly's permission, I'll throw the solution into this answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Should I then simply increase the count?

Comment: @WhozCraig I can see what is wrong now but I am unsure how to avoid this. I cannot see any other way to do this :/

Comment: @ASgelly  I can see what is wrong now but I am unsure how to avoid this. I cannot see any other way to do this

Comment: you need something like `int count[MAXINT]`

Comment: @Danielle one method posted. hope you find it helpful.